# making my iso file bootable?

Tags: dual-boot

How do I make  the downloaded ISO file on my USB drive bootable so i can install it? I have downloaded the ISO file and do not know what to do next to install it and make it dual boot with windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a bootable USB using your ISO. On Windows you can do that with 
[Rufus](https://rufus.ie), and on a Mac - with [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/). To dual boot with Windows, install elementary OS on a separate partition.

For details please read [this article](https://elementary.io/docs/installation) or [this one](https://www.lifewire.com/create-elementary-os-live-usb-drive-2202054).